# PHP/AJAX stoping jquery from working?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Having the issue here where my jquery work fine when viewing it as a single page however when I try and include that PHP file in another page either using php include or ajax the jquery doesnt seem to load.

I'm rather new to all this stuff so its very possible I'm doing something silly, any help would be greatly appreciated!

**HTML Code**

```
 <html>
<head>

<script>
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
//xmlhttp.open("GET","jquery.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<form>
<select name="users" ID="option" onChange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a person:</option>
<option value="1">ID One</option>
<option value="2">ID Two</option>
<option value="3">ID Three</option>
<option value="4">ID Four</option>
</select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>

</body>

</html>
```

**PHP/Jquery**

```
 <html>
<head>





<link href="../../Styles/tablestyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<?php include "db.php" ?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../../JS/tablesorter/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../JS/tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../JS/sorter.js"></script> 

<script>


$(document).ready(function() { 
    // call the tablesorter plugin 
    $("table").tablesorter({ 
        // sort on the first column and third column, order asc 
        sortList: [[0,0],[2,0]] 
    }); 


});
</script>

<?php

$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$result = mysqli_query($db_connection, "SELECT * FROM student WHERE Student_Id = '".$q."' or Student_Id = 7");

echo "<table id=\"myTable\" class=\"tablesorter\"> 
<thead> 
<tr> 
    <th>Student ID</th> 
    <th>B-Code</th> 
    <th>First Name</th> 
    <th>Second Name</th> 
    <th>Email</th> 
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody>

";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Student_Id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['B-code'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Student_Forename'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Student_Surename'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Student_Email'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";

}

echo"</tbody> 
</table> ";



mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: So you're including an entire page, head, body and everything, into the head section of another page ?

Comment: really unclear what you are including in another page

Comment: Nit picks: Use prepared statements instead of passing variables directly into your queries. Additionally, don't use " if you aren't substituting variables into the string, else the interpreter is going to parse those strings for no reason.

Comment: Try `if (include('db.php') == 'OK') {
    echo 'OK';
}` to see if the PHP is included without error.

Comment: Check your PHP or HTTP server logs for errors as well

Comment: are those two pages at same level? relative paths can break if both files are not in the same folder of at the same level

Comment: These are the two pages, one html page and the other php. The HTML page is used to allow the user to select options from the dropdown list and php page is using ajax and php to query the db on the option the user selected.

Comment: both are on the same level, im just testing at the moment

Comment: As a warning, please do not deface your question and attempt to vandalize the answers of others: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3541351 http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3541348

Answer (score 0):

Your AJAX request is going to getuser.php, which is what I'm going to assume your second code block represents? Basically instead of making a call to some PHP code that does your processing and sending you a response, you're actually calling back a PHP script AND an HTML page to boot, then embedding that into an existing page.

I recommend doing the following:

First, remove the HTML from getuser.php so that all you have left is the PHP code.

Then, in the page making the AJAX call, as part of your "success" function, include your sorter function so that it occurs after you've gotten your response and written out the new HTML. Something to the effect of the following:

getuser.php:

```
<?php include "db.php";


$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$result = mysqli_query($db_connection, "SELECT * FROM student WHERE Student_Id = '".$q."' or Student_Id = 7");

echo "<table id=\"myTable\" class=\"tablesorter\"> 
<thead> 
<tr> 
    <th>Student ID</th> 
    <th>B-Code</th> 
    <th>First Name</th> 
    <th>Second Name</th> 
    <th>Email</th> 
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody>

";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Student_Id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['B-code'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Student_Forename'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Student_Surename'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Student_Email'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";

}

echo"</tbody> 
</table> ";



mysqli_close($con);
```

Then, in your calling page success code:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
$("table").tablesorter({ 
        // sort on the first column and third column, order asc 
        sortList: [[0,0],[2,0]] 
    }); 

    }
  }
```

Also, move your necessary CSS and JavaScript includes to the calling page as well so that you have your jQuery object available, etc. I would also recommend changing that code to use jQuery contructs and functions instead of raw JavaScript. It'll help keep your code clean, consistent, and easier to read :)

NOTE: I typed this up in a hurry, so anyone feel free to call me out and correct me on any mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much what I thnk is the issue is that when your jQuery script fires,the default functionality of the selector statements is select and do this on the current instances of this selector.

So if you do:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // call the tablesorter plugin 
    $("table").tablesorter({ 
        // sort on the first column and third column, order asc 
        sortList: [[0,0],[2,0]] 
    }); 
});
```

That finds all of the table tags on the page, and calls tablesorter on them. But, if additional table tags are added to the page, or the first table tag is added to the page when the page has already loaded, then jquery does not call table sorter onto it because it did not exist previously when it ran the `$("table")` selector.

This is not tested, but you can try and hook the .tablesorter onto the $("table") selector once everytime ajax finishes loading.

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
        $("table").tablesorter({ 
                // sort on the first column and third column, order asc 
                sortList: [[0,0],[2,0]] 
        }); 
});
```

A similiar situation is when you use something like:

```
$( "#target" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

The .click event is only bound to the #target elements that existed on the page when the page first loaded. Any subsequent #target elements added to the page later on will not have the .click event bound to them.

So say. You have header.php, where your script lives. Then you have `index.php`, and then you have `table.php`. If you include `header.php` inside `index.php`, the scripts inside `header.php` will effect the elements in `index.php`. But if you also include `table.php` inside of `index.php`, the scripts in `header.php` will not effect the elements in `table.php` unless you use the appropriate event binding like the `.on()` event below. I think...?

To resolve this, you have to use the .on event:

```
$( "#target" ).on( "click", function() {
  alert( $( this ).text() );
});
```

The .on event will bind itself to all current, and later instances of the selector, in this example the selector is #target.

Comment: Thanks Ron, No luck I'm afraid. I'm having the same issue with loading static php pages, the jquery runs fine when looking at the page directly but when I use methods like .load or include the to load the page on from another the jquery doesn't seem to work. Even if i apply the jquery to main page.

Comment: Have you tried adding your script into the foot of the page you are loading so that they load in after the content has loaded? Also, just to confirm do the scripts work if you include them on the same page that you are loading? If you access it directly does the jquery work fine? Also, just checking the obvious here, but make sure you are including jquery before you u are calling these scripts.

Comment: Yeah tried all that :( Jquery work when access that page directly it just when you load the page from another using php / ajax the jquery stops completely. I've even tried adding in some static animation jquery and again only work when accessing the page directly. It must be how the pages are being loaded.

Comment: instead of using `XMLHttpRequest()` have you considered just using the built in jquery ajax: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Hi Ron, Sorry about that. Wasn't actually me this is a group account for a mini project i'm working on one of the guys deleted the code (or at least tried to).